# ANN Library problems in Fedora

Tags: c++, linux, build, compiler-errors, g++

Have you had success installing ANN recently? (http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/)

In my computer and using the latest version available on the website, I seem to be able to install it from running `make`. But I can't correctly compile a program that uses it. According to the official manual you just have to compile with  `g++ a.cpp  -Iann/include -Lann/lib -lANN` but my compiler returns:
`fatal error: ANN/ANN.h: No such file or directory`

Has anybody been able to install it in Fedora or other linux system? Or do you have any idea of how to get it to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to solve it by changing "`ann`" by the path to the library root directory in "`g++ a.cpp -Iann/include -Lann/lib -lANN`".